# 2 pixel mouse cursor accuracy on Mavericks with Retina Display

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, mouseevent, retina-display

I am working with an app that should be able to handle retina graphics. The problem I have is that while the screen is in retina mode, the mouse pointer still seem to move in low res mode. If I move the mouse it will jump two pixels each move making it impossible for me to hover half of the pixels in the image.

I have tried two ways of acquiring the mouse position.

On of then is to utilize the [NSWindow mouseLocationOutsideOfEventStream]; I can confirm that I only get non-retina precision on mouse position for this call. (However NSPoint has float values for X and Y so I would love if it would at least return .5 for the in between pixels)

I have also tried ro register for mouseMoved using NSTrackingArea:

```
NSTrackingArea *const trackingArea = [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:NSZeroRect options:(NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingMouseMoved | NSTrackingActiveAlways | NSTrackingInVisibleRect) owner:self userInfo:nil];
[self addTrackingArea:trackingArea];

-(void)mouseMoved:(NSEvent *)theEvent {}
```

Neither of these seem to give me 1-pixel accuracy they both jump two pixel-steps for the smallest mouse move.

Any ideas of how I can accomplish retina accuracy from the mouse cursor position?

Comment: How are you extracting the coordinates exactly? You may take scaling into account...

Comment: in mouseMoved I get the coordinates from theEvent and I have also tried [NSWindow mouseLocationOutsideOfEventStream] as written in the question. I don't think there is a scaling issue. Since the coordinates delivered are not changing unless I move the mouse enough to step 2 pixels.

Comment: Maybe you seem to get wrong values, but need to convert them to backing, which is scaled on a retina display. For rects and sizes you have to do that as well, so maybe it is necessary in your case as well...

Answer (score 2):

You can not move mouse cursor with 1-pixel accuracy in retina mode because hardware reports movements on a resolution-independent scale. Otherwise your cursor speed would be not the same on retina and non-retina displays with identical mouse or touchpad settings.

One solution is to hide system cursor and draw your own, moving it with with 1-pixel accuracy and putting back system cursor. I believe color picker of system utility ColorSync was made by that way.